# Attaching an Eclipse detached view programmatically

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp

I have programmatically detached a view from eclipse.
now I want to attach it back.
What is the best efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matching operation for `detach(*)` is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService.insert(MPartSashContainerElement, MPartSashContainerElement, int, float)`.

The only working example I found was in the DND support [SplitDropAgent](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/addons/dndaddon/SplitDropAgent.java#n367), but it's not easy to read.  I suspect you need to find the part that you have previously detached.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some cast-validity and null-validity checks but here's the deal:

```
PartSite partSite = (PartSite)yourDetachedView.getViewSite();
PartPane partPane = partSite.getPane();
ViewStack viewStack = (ViewStack)partPane.getContainer();
ViewPane viewPane = (ViewPane)viewStack.getSelection();
viewPane.doAttach();
```

EDIT:  Here's another way.

```
PartSite site = (PartSite)yourDetachedView.getSite();
WorkbenchPage workbenchPage = (WorkbenchPage)site.getPage();
String viewId = site.getId();
String secondaryId = yourDetachedView.getViewSite().getSecondaryId();
IViewReference viewReference = workbenchPage.findViewReference( viewId, secondaryId );
Perspective activePerspective = workbenchPage.getActivePerspective();
PerspectiveHelper presentation = activePerspective.getPresentation();
presentation.attachPart( viewReference );
```

Comment: PerspectiveHelper presentation = activePerspective.getPresentation(); ???? nothing

Comment: How did you detach your view?

Comment: modelService.detach(
           partStashContainerElement, x, y,
           width, height);

Comment: Oh, e4, right?  Sorry, can't help you with that.  I still work with 3.x.  But I'd like to know the answer to your question.